# Discord bot does nothing when command is ran

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Hello so I want to create a bot that plays audio using youtube link. Its for my firiends discord I tought I could make it by myself. So I used some of my javascript knowledge and it turns out that my knowledge is not quite good as I tought. :)

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const token = 'blablalblalbalbalbalbalbalbalblab';

// Create a new Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: 7796})

// Import the BOT_TOKEN from the .env file


// This function will be called when the bot is ready to connect to Discord
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

// This function will be called when the bot receives a message
client.on('message', message => {
    // Check if the message starts with the !play command
    if (message.content.startsWith('!play')) {
        // Get the YouTube link from the message
        const youtubeLink = message.content.split(' ')[1];

        // Check if the user is in a voice channel
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
            // Join the user's voice channel
            const connection = message.member.voice.channel.join();

            // Play the audio from the YouTube link
            const stream = ytdl(youtubeLink, { filter: 'audioonly' });
            const dispatcher = connection.play(stream);

            // Log a message when the audio starts playing
            dispatcher.on('start', () => {
                console.log('Playing audio...');
            });

            // Log a message when the audio finishes playing
            dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
                console.log('Finished playing audio.');
            });
        } else {
            // If the user is not in a voice channel, send a message telling them to join a voice channel first
            message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
        }
    }
});

client.login(token)
```

I expected bot to work but it doesn't.

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Answer (score 0):

it is messageCreate if you are using the new version

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {})
```